# Regex string replace with Grunt

Tags: regex, replace, gruntjs

I'm trying to string replace this using regex

`url('sprites-s1da6ddca7c.png')`

to `url({{'sprites-s1da6ddca7c.png' | asset_url}})`

and the sprite file name is generated automatically so basically need to look for `url('sprites-` *wildcard `.png')`

this is the plugin i was going to use: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-string-replace which looks pretty easy to implement once i've figured out the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple regex to match such patterns and capture the name you could use a regex like:

```
\burl\(('sprites-\w+\.png')\)
```